# Android studio - gradle - setting proxy per android studio installation not per project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After the last update of android studio, it converted all my projects. Now the proxy is set in every project like following:

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
systemProp.http.proxyHost=PROXY_HOST
systemProp.http.proxyUser=USERNAME
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

No I use two machines with android studio installed and I'd like to set the proxy not in the `gradle.properties` file but somewhere in android studio, globally. Is that still somehow possible?

**WHY?**

I only need the proxy on one machine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define a "global" gradle.properties file.

Create a gradle.properties containing the properties that you want to apply to all projects. Put this file in `<USER_HOME>`/.gradle`. It should then be applied to all projects.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks